# Почему может дергаться страница при прокрутке по клику на пункт меню?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть [страница](http://victorpavloff.tmweb.ru/abc/ballet/). При клике на пункты меню страница прокручивается к нужному блоку. Но прокрутка происходит рывками. Почему так может происходить?

**JS:**

```
$(".scroll").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var full_url = this.href;
        var parts = full_url.split("#");
        var trgt = parts[1];
        var target_offset = $("#"+trgt).offset();
        var target_top = target_offset.top;
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:target_top}, 500);
    });
```

Comment: Надо смотреть скрипт, отвечающий за прокрутку, дёргается не постоянно, периодически

Comment: Скрипт добавил в вопрос

Comment: У меня была подобная проблема, из-за кривой вёрстки, где-то тэг забыл закрыть.

Comment: У меня с вёрсткой всё нормально. Нет не ошибок, не предупреждений через W3C валидатор.

Comment: у меня нормально всё отображается , без дерганий

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, сам jQ подтормаживает, именно метод .animate(). Попробуйте использовать плагин AnchorScroller.js (к сожалению, не знаю, кто автор). Нашёл его когда-то в сети и немного доработал, он, кажется,  работает более плавно. Для запуска достаточно повесить 2 атрибута: 1) на ссылку к якорю `data-anchor`, 2) на якорь `data-anchor-id`, в вашем случае

```
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#presentation" data-anchor>Презентация</a></li>
   <li><a href="#costing"data-anchor>Расчет стоимости</a></li>
   <li><a href="#request" data-anchor>Заявка</a></li>
 </ul>

 <section id="presentation" data-anchor-id></section>
 <section id="costing" data-anchor-id></section>
 <section id="request" data-anchor-id></section>
```

**Обновление:** хотя, пожалуй, не более плавно, но не зависает, как при использовании .animate() Также заметил, что плавность зависит от области просмотра, если нажать "Выполнить код" и не разворачивать пример на весь экран, то работает плавно, если же просматривать страницу в развёрнутом режиме - начинаются подёргивания. Предположу, что это связано с особенностями рендеринга в браузерах, и большое количество разметки может приводить к подтормаживанию.

```js
//Плавный переход к якорю
function anchorScroller(el, duration) {
 if (this.criticalSection) {
 return false;
 }
 
 if ((typeof el != 'object') || (typeof el.href != 'string'))
 return true;
 
 var address = el.href.split('#');
 if (address.length < 2)
 return true;
 
 address = address[address.length-1];
 el = 0;
 
 for (var i=0; i < jQuery('[data-anchor-id]').length; i++) {
 if (jQuery('[data-anchor-id]')[i].id == address) {
   el = jQuery('[data-anchor-id]')[i];
   break;
 }
 }
 if (el === 0)
 return true;
 
 this.stopX = 0;
 this.stopY = 0;
 do {
 this.stopX += el.offsetLeft;
 this.stopY += el.offsetTop;
 } while (el = el.offsetParent);
 
 this.startX = document.documentElement.scrollLeft || window.pageXOffset || document.body.scrollLeft;
 this.startY = document.documentElement.scrollTop || window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop;
 
 this. stopX = this.stopX - this.startX;
 this.stopY = this.stopY - this.startY;
 
 if ( (this.stopX == 0) && (this.stopY == 0) )
 return false;
 
 this.criticalSection = true;
 if (typeof duration == 'undefined')
 this.duration = 500;
 else
 this.duration = duration;
 
 var date = new Date();
 this.start = date.getTime();
 this.timer = setInterval(function () {
 var date = new Date();
 var X = (date.getTime() - this.start) / this.duration;
 if (X > 1)
 X = 1;
 var Y = ((-Math.cos(X*Math.PI)/2) + 0.5);
 
 cX = Math.round(this.startX + this.stopX*Y);
 cY = Math.round(this.startY + this.stopY*Y);
 
 document.documentElement.scrollLeft = cX;
 document.documentElement.scrollTop = cY;
 document.body.scrollLeft = cX;
 document.body.scrollTop = cY;
 
 if (X == 1) {
   clearInterval( this.timer);
   this.criticalSection = false;
 }
 }, 0);
 return false;
}
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery('body').on('click', '[data-anchor]', function() {
  return anchorScroller(this);
 });
});
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

/* fonts */

@font-face {
 font-family: "PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-THIN";
 src: url("../fonts/PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-THIN.eot");
 src: url("../fonts/PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-THIN.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
 url("../fonts/PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-THIN.woff") format("woff"),
 url("../fonts/PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-THIN.ttf") format("truetype"),
 url("../fonts/PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-THIN.svg#PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-THIN") format("svg");
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: "PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-LIGHT";
 src: url("../fonts/PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-LIGHT.eot");
 src: url("../fonts/PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-LIGHT.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
 url("../fonts/PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-LIGHT.woff") format("woff"),
 url("../fonts/PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-LIGHT.ttf") format("truetype"),
 url("../fonts/PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-LIGHT.svg#PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-LIGHT") format("svg");
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: "PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-REGULAR";
 src: url("../fonts/PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-REGULAR.eot");
 src: url("../fonts/PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-REGULAR.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
 url("../fonts/PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-REGULAR.woff") format("woff"),
 url("../fonts/PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-REGULAR.ttf") format("truetype"),
 url("../fonts/PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-REGULAR.svg#PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-REGULAR") format("svg");
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: "PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-MEDIUM";
 src: url("../fonts/PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-MEDIUM.eot");
 src: url("../fonts/PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-MEDIUM.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
 url("../fonts/PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-MEDIUM.woff") format("woff"),
 url("../fonts/PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-MEDIUM.ttf") format("truetype"),
 url("../fonts/PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-MEDIUM.svg#PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-MEDIUM") format("svg");
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}

/* page */

body {
 min-width: 1170px;
 background: #fff;
 color: #4e4a52; 
}

.wrapper {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 1150px;
}

.clearfix:after {
 content: ".";
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 clear: both;
 visibility: hidden;
}

/* header */

header {
 height: 165px;
 background: url(../images/logo.png) center 20px no-repeat; 
}

header .wrapper {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 67px 10px 0 10px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1240px;
 min-width: 1150px;
 font-family: "PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-MEDIUM";
}

header nav {
 float: left;
 margin: 2px 0 0 0;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

header nav li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0 37px 0 0; 
}

header nav a {
 color: #ada6b3;
 text-decoration: none;
 outline: none;
}

header nav a:hover {
 color: #4e4a52;
}

header .phone {
 float: right;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #89729e;
}

/* presentation */

#presentation {
 margin: 0 auto;
 min-width: 1170px;
 max-width: 1920px;
 height: 697px;
 background: url(../images/presentation_background.jpg) center no-repeat #e2eaf2;
}

#presentation .wrapper {
 padding: 168px 0 0 0; 
}

#presentation h1 {
 font-family: "PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-THIN";
 font-size: 56px;
 line-height: 67px;
 text-align: center;
}

#presentation .button {
 display: block;
 margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
 width: 323px;
 height: 80px;
 border: 1px solid #89729e;
 -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
 -moz-border-radius: 40px;
 border-radius: 40px;
 font-family: "PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-REGULAR";
 font-size: 28px;
 line-height: 76px;
 color: #89729e;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 outline: none;
}

#presentation .button:hover {
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
}

/* costing */

#costing .wrapper {
 padding: 70px 0 0 0;
}

#costing h2 {
 font-family: "PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-LIGHT";
 font-size: 36px;
 text-align: center;
}

#costing p {
 margin: 10px 0 70px 0;
 font-family: "PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-THIN";
 font-size: 24px;
 text-align: center;
}

#costing .sliders {
 float: left;
 margin: 0 0 80px 0;
 width: 880px;
 height: 250px; 
}

#costing .item {
 height: 47px;
}

#costing .item.groups {
 margin: 54px 0 55px 0; 
}

#costing .item p {
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 width: 220px;
 height: 47px;
 font-family: "PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-REGULAR";
 font-size: 26px;
 line-height: 47px;
 text-align: left;
}

#costing .slider {
 float: left;
 width: 480px;
 height: 10px; 
}

#costing input {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 0 0 45px;
 padding: 0 10px;
 width: 47px;
 height: 47px;
 border: none;
 -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
 -moz-border-radius: 8px;
 border-radius: 8px;
 background: #f9f8fa;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 0 #e4e3e5 inset;
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 0 #e4e3e5 inset;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 0 #e4e3e5 inset;
 outline: none;
 font-family: "PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-REGULAR";
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #4e4a52;
 text-align: center;
}

#costing .arrows {
 float: left;
 margin: 0 0 0 12px;
 padding: 5px 0;
 width: 19px;
 height: 37px;
}

#costing .arrows .arrow_up {
 margin: 0 0 15px 0;
 width: 19px;
 height: 11px;
 background: url(../images/arrows.png) left top no-repeat;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#costing .arrows .arrow_up:hover {
 background: url(../images/arrows.png) right top no-repeat;
}

#costing .arrows .arrow_down {
 width: 19px;
 height: 11px;
 background: url(../images/arrows.png) left bottom no-repeat;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#costing .arrows .arrow_down:hover {
 background: url(../images/arrows.png) right bottom no-repeat;
}

#costing .profit {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 0 80px 0;
 padding: 40px 0 0 0;
 width: 270px;
 height: 250px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
 -moz-border-radius: 8px;
 border-radius: 8px;
 background: #f9f8fa; 
}

#costing .profit .title {
 margin: 0 0 42px 0;
 font-family: "PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-REGULAR";
 font-size: 30px;
}

#costing .profit .value {
 margin: 0;
 font-family: "PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-REGULAR";
 font-size: 72px;
 color: #e78e92;
}

#costing .profit .currency {
 margin: 0;
 font-family: "PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-REGULAR";
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #e78e92;
}

#costing .button {
 clear: both;
 display: block;
 width: 260px;
 height: 60px;
 margin: 0 auto 75px auto;
 -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
 -moz-border-radius: 30px;
 border-radius: 30px;
 background: #e78e92;
 outline: none;
 font-family: "PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-REGULAR";
 font-size: 26px;
 line-height: 56px;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
}

#costing .button:hover {
 background: #e37b80;
}

/* request */

#request {
 margin: 0 auto;
 min-width: 1170px;
 max-width: 1920px;
 height: 764px;
 background: url(../images/request_background.jpg) center no-repeat #e3b59e;
 position: relative;
}

#request .wrapper {
 padding: 70px 0 0 0;
}

#request h2 {
 font-family: "PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-LIGHT";
 font-size: 36px;
 text-align: center;
}

#request .form_box {
 width: 516px;
 height: 575px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
 border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -258px;
 bottom: 0;
}

#request form {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 30px 40px 0 40px;
 width: 516px;
 height: 575px;
}

#request form .input_box {
 position: relative; 
}

#request form .input_box label {
 height: 46px;
 font-family: "PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-THIN";
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 46px;
 color: #d86782;
 cursor: text;
 position: absolute;
 right: 18px;
 bottom: 0;
}

#request form .input_title {
 font-family: "PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-REGULAR";
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #8e8a91;
}

#request form input {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: block;
 margin: 6px 0 25px 0;
 padding: 0 19px;
 width: 436px;
 height: 46px;
 border: none;
 -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
 -moz-border-radius: 8px;
 border-radius: 8px;
 background: #fff;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 0 #e9e9ea inset;
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 0 #e9e9ea inset;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 0 #e9e9ea inset;
 outline: none;
 font-family: "PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-REGULAR";
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #4e4a52;
}

#request form input:focus {
 padding: 0 18px;
 border: 1px solid #dbd6e0;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 0 #e9e9ea inset;
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 0 #e9e9ea inset;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 0 #e9e9ea inset;
}

#request form input[name="email"] {
 margin: 6px 0 0 0; 
}

#request form input.error {
 border: 1px solid #e78e92; 
}

#request form .text {
 margin: 15px 0 30px 0;
 font-family: "PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-LIGHT";
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #d86782;
 text-align: center;
}

#request form button {
 display: block;
 width: 220px;
 height: 60px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 0 5px 0;
 border: none;
 -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
 -moz-border-radius: 30px;
 border-radius: 30px;
 background: #e78e92;
 outline: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-family: "PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-REGULAR";
 font-size: 26px;
 color: #fff;
}

#request form button:hover {
 background: #e37b80;
}

#request .form_box .success {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 230px 0 0 0;
 width: 516px;
 height: 575px;
 display: none;
}

#request .form_box .success p {
 font-family: "PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-THIN";
 font-size: 36px;
 line-height: 48px;
 text-align: center;
}

#request .form_box .success span {
 font-family: "PFDINTEXTCONDPRO-LIGHT";
 font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
        
        <!-- header -->
        
        <header>
            <div class="wrapper">
                
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#presentation" data-anchor>Презентация</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#costing"data-anchor>Расчет стоимости</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#request" data-anchor>Заявка</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                
                <div class="phone">8 812 603-42-42</div>
                
            </div>
        </header>
        
        <!-- /header -->
        
        <!-- presentation -->
        
        <section id="presentation" data-anchor-id>
            <div class="wrapper">
                
                <h1>Франшиза детской<br>хореографической школы<br>«Русский балет»</h1>
                <a href="http://franshiza-futbolnogo-kluba.ru/Content/documents/junior-franchise.pdf" target="_blank" class="button">Открыть презентацию</a>
                
            </div>
        </section>
        
        <!-- /presentation -->
        
        <!-- costing -->
        
        <section id="costing" data-anchor-id>
            <div class="wrapper">
                
                <h2>Рассчитайте прибыльность вашей школы</h2>
                <p>В расчет включены затраты на зарплату хореографов, аренду зала, рекламу, роялти и налоги</p>
                
                <div class="sliders">
                    
                    <!-- pupils -->
                    
                    <div class="item pupils clearfix">
                        
                        <p>Количество учениц</p>
                        
                        <div class="slider pupils_slider"></div>
                        
                        <input type="text" name="pupils" value="0">
                        
                        <div class="arrows">
                            <div class="arrow_up"></div>
                            <div class="arrow_down"></div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- /pupils -->
                    
                    <!-- groups -->
                    
                    <div class="item groups clearfix">
                        
                        <p>Количество групп</p>
                        
                        <div class="slider groups_slider"></div>
                        
                        <input type="text" name="groups" value="0">
                        
                        <div class="arrows">
                            <div class="arrow_up"></div>
                            <div class="arrow_down"></div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- /groups -->
                    
                    <!-- schools -->
                    
                    <div class="item schools clearfix">
                        
                        <p>Количество школ</p>
                        
                        <div class="slider schools_slider"></div>
                        
                        <input type="text" name="schools" value="0">
                        
                        <div class="arrows">
                            <div class="arrow_up"></div>
                            <div class="arrow_down"></div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- /schools -->
                    
                </div>
                
                <!-- profit -->
                
                <div class="profit">
                    <p class="title">Ваша прибыль</p>
                    <p class="value">0</p>
                    <p class="currency">рублей</p>
                </div>
                
                <!-- /profit -->
                
                <a href="#" class="button">Заполнить анкету</a>
                
            </div>
        </section>
        
        <!-- /costing -->
        
        <!-- request -->
        
        <section id="request" data-anchor-id>
            <div class="wrapper">
                
                <h2>Оставьте заявку, и мы свяжемся с вами</h2>
                
                <div class="form_box">
                    
                    <!-- form -->
                    
                    <form action="php/send.php" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
                        
                        <div class="input_box">
                            <p class="input_title">Имя</p>
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="input_box">
                            <p class="input_title">Телефон</p>
                            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="input_box">
                            <p class="input_title">Город проживания</p>
                            <input type="text" name="city" id="city">
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="input_box">
                            <p class="input_title">E-mail</p>
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
                        </div>
                        
                        <p class="text">Все поля обязательны для заполнения</p>
                        
                        <button>Отправить</button>
                        
                    </form>
                    
                    <!-- /form -->
                    
                    <!-- success -->
                    
                    <div class="success">
                        <p>Спасибо. Заявка отправлена.<br>
                        <span>Мы скоро свяжемся с вами</span></p>
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- /success -->
                
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </section>
    
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Romanzhivo/06Lk3bc3/

Comment: Спасибо за подробный комментарий!

Comment: @Виктор Павлов, пожалуйста, но, как я понимаю, это особо не решило проблему? :)

Comment: Нет, не решило.

Answer (score 0):

ммм , рывки из за подгрузки во время скроллинга , попробуй увеличить или же уменьшить скорость анимации , и сменить темп , мне лично помогло , далее такое действительно может происходить при плотной подгонке контуров элементов на странице отступ контейнера хотя бы в 3 пикселя исправит , если проблема в этом , ну в общем выдвинул свои предположения , дальше разбираться вам )